# Горячие клавиши в режиме кириллической раскладки zathura

Tags: linux, pdf, config, hotkeys, vi

Характерность моего вопроса заключается в следующем, zathura (document viewer) располагает подобной связностью комбинаторных сочетаний клавиш: **h - влево, j - вниз, k - вверх, l - вправо** и т. п. Возможно ли выполнение данных методов управления без учета установленной раскладки? Благодарю!

Comment: скорей всего — нет... конечно не считая возможности подправить исходники...

Comment: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-zathurarc/ ...и так же посмотреть что в *~/.inputrc*.